# Change meeting options of a team's event using ms graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to change meeting options of a created event via MS graph api. But I couldn't locate a endpoint to get this done. Can any one help me on this?

[Meeting options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRSw9.png)